# Docker Problem, entrypoint file.sh doesnt recognize the su-exec command

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch, alpine-linux

I am trying to build a docker image that has elastic search running and creating a container from that image.

Below is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine

MAINTAINER rando

COPY  elasticsearch-2.1.1.tar.gz /tmp

RUN    cd /tmp  \
    && tar -xzf  elasticsearch-2.1.1.tar.gz  \ 
    && ls    \
    && mv elasticsearch-2.1.1   /usr/share/elasticsearch   \
    && ls /usr/share \
       && adduser -DH -s /sbin/nologin elasticsearch \
       && chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch \
       && echo "Creating Elasticsearch Paths..." \
       && for path in /usr/share/elasticsearch/data /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs /usr/share/elasticsearch/config /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins ; do mkdir -p "$path"; done \
       && chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch \
       && ls /usr/share/elasticsearch 

COPY elasticsearch.yml  /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
COPY elastic-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /elastic-entrypoint.sh 

ENV  ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch   
ENV  PATH=${ES_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

RUN echo "$PATH"

VOLUME ["/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]

EXPOSE 9200 9300

ENTRYPOINT ["/elastic-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["elasticsearch"]
```

I am to build successfully the image from the docker file when running the command below:

```
docker build -t elasticsearch .
```

When I try to create the container with the command below, I am facing some issues:

```
docker run -d --network host elasticsearch
```

The container is created but is terminates directly.

Below is the content when running the docker logs for the container:

```
/elastic-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 20: su-exec: not found
```

Below is the content of elastic-entrypoint.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# Add elasticsearch as command if needed
if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
    set -- elasticsearch "$@"
fi

# Drop root privileges if we are running elasticsearch
# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'elasticsearch' -a "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    # Change the ownership of /usr/share/elasticsearch/data to elasticsearch
    chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

    set -- su-exec elasticsearch tini -- "$@"
fi


exec "$@"
```

It seems that `set -- su-exec elasticsearch tini -- "$@"` is not working.

I will appreciate any help or guidance to fix this issue.

Regards,
Rando.

Update............................................................

I modified the file as below:

```
    #set -- su-exec elasticsearch tini -- "$@"
    set -- su -c elasticsearch tini -- "$@"
```

It showed the error:

```
su: unknown user tini
```

It is not recognizing the user.

Update 2...............................................................

I modified the dockerfile by adding the command for installation of `su-exe` like below:

```
# Install required packages
RUN apk add --no-cache bash su-exec
```

The container exited with the error below:

```
su-exec: tini: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error was that `adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine`does not include the su-exec package. I modified the dockerfile as below:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine

MAINTAINER rando

# Install required packages
RUN apk add --no-cache bash su-exec
RUN apk add --update tini

COPY  elasticsearch-2.1.1.tar.gz /tmp

...
```

And adding `su-exec` package fixed the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `set -- su -c elasticsearch tini -- "$@"`

Also you do not need to define `CMD ["elasticsearch"]` inside Dockerfile. Just put inside elastic-entrypoint.sh file.

Comment: Splitting `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` as shown in the question is good practice.  You could, for example, `docker run --rm -it this-image sh` to get a debugging shell in a temporary container based on the built image, having done the rest of the setup script; you don't need the awkward `--entrypoint` option.

Comment: I tried  used su -c, but it failed to recognize the user. It printed : su: unknown user tini